# flutter how to remove gap from left side in CarouselSlider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-slider

I want to show the all images from the API in the carousel and for items, I want to show 2 items per slide. and it works correctly what I want. but at the first item, it gives me a gap from the left side. anyone know how can i remove this gap from left side.

here is my code:-

```
class PersonImages extends StatefulWidget {

PersonImages({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
_PersonImages createState() => _PersonImages();
}

class _PersonImages extends State<PersonImages>{

var UsriD = Auth.prefs?.getString('usrid');
var Imagedata;
var img = "";
var user = "";



@override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();
 getImageData();
}

getImageData() async{
var res = await http.get(Uri.https('www.*******.net', '/index.php',{'act':'usrPhotos','Usrid': '${UsriD}'}));
Imagedata = jsonDecode(res.body);
setState(() {});
print(res.body);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return
  Imagedata != null? CarouselSlider.builder(
      options: CarouselOptions(
        aspectRatio: 2.0,
        enableInfiniteScroll: false,
        enlargeCenterPage: false,
        viewportFraction: 0.5,
      ),
      itemCount: Imagedata.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index, int  pageViewIndex) {
        //final int first = index * 2;
        //final int second = first + 1;
       return
         Row(
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child:  Container(
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
                      child:
                      Image.network(
                        "https://www.*******.net/files/images/${Imagedata[index]['image']}",
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: 300,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                      ),
                    ),

                ),
              )
              ),
        ]
          );
      }
  ): const Center(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
  );
  }
  }
```

Here is my output:- [image: there is clearly see that there is gap from left side]

please help me if anyone knows how to resolve it. is anyone knows how to do this so answer my question?

Comment: comment this and try again `viewportFraction: 0.5,`

Comment: if i comment this then it show me 1 item per slide and i want to show 2 items per slide so that's why i do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set initial page

```
initialPage: 1,
```

also change

```
enableInfiniteScroll: true,
```

Comment: still same issue